# PSD to HTML conversion font-weight issue

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am using a font family `font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Bold';` which is used in the PSD and I am using the same font on its HTML conversion. But I am facing a issue there is some difference of font-weight when I check it on the browser.
Can you please let me know why the same font uses more font weight on the browser.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please tell us, how did you tried it? Actually its typekit fonts. We need to use script of fonts inside Head section. Or if you have .ttf or .otf fonts you can generate from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Actually I am using offline font (ProximaNovaA-Bold TTF File) which I have generated from the online site webfont generator, after generating the file I directly pasted all the generated font type into my font folder and call it by directly its font family name which is "font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Bold'"

Comment: Then check css where you have pasted. Need to correct path of generated fonts.

Comment: You may not be able to match font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Bold'; from PSD, its better to use the web font of same weight in order to match visual appearance. Ref : https://fonts.google.com/?query=Proxima+Nova. Some of the website providing free web fonts.

Comment: Bro path for the generated font is correctly linked even the font also loads on the browser but some font weight difference is there if I matched the font with the psd font weight.

Comment: *What* is the font weight difference? Can you post screen caps?

Comment: Yes Sure here is the file:
Here is a font thickness difference (FONT WEIGHT)
PSD Capture Url: https://ibb.co/guHB1K
HTML Generated Url: https://ibb.co/feD11K

Comment: add you html & css code here

Comment: Here is the code that I am using on the site:
 'font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Bold';    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 0.32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 28.5px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;'

Comment: Font Family Calling on my css:

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaA-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNovaA-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNovaA-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNovaA-Bold.svg#ProximaNovaA-Bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}